# /bin/sh equivalent of bash ${!var_*} expansion

Tags: bash, sh

bash expands !var_* to defined vars that match the wildcard ($var_1 $var_2 etc.), e.g.

```
var_1=''
var_2=''
for v in ${!var_*}; do echo $v; done
```

returns 'var_1' and 'var_2' strings

What would be the textbook approach to iterating through defined vars in a similar manner with /bin/sh?  (It will save having to install bash.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe enough?

```
var_1=''
var_2=''
for v in `set | sed -n '/^var_/s/=.*//p'`
do
    echo $v
done

echo ======

var_3=''
for v in `set | sed -n '/^var_/s/=.*//p'`
do
    echo $v
done
```

will print

```
var_1
var_2
======
var_1
var_2
var_3
```

Comment: Now I did not know `set` did that, prints the values of all defined names.

Comment: yes, it is like `printenv` but prints all variables, not only exported ones.